# Only Two Isomorphism Classes of Groups of Order Four

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism

So my textbook says that there are two classifications of groups of order four. Those two are:

$\mathbb{Z}_4\cong\{0,1,2,3\}$ under $+_4$, and

$\mathbb{K}_4\cong$ symmetry group of a (non-square) rectangle.

It also says if $P\cong Q$, and $P$ has $k$ elements of order $n$, then $Q$ has $k$ elements of order $n$. And that groups of order 8 or less can be classified entirely by the orders of their elements.

---

So, let $(O,N)$ describe a group, $A$, such that $O$ represents an order (where $O$ divides $|A|$) and $N$ represents the number of elements (in the underlying set of $A$) with that respective order $O$.

---

Let $G$ be a group such that $|G|=4$.

$G$ can only be broken down in one of the following ways the following ways:

$G_1=(1,1),(2,3)$

$G_2=(1,1),(2,2),(4,1)$

$G_3=(1,1),(2,1),(4,2)$

$G_4=(1,1),(4,3)$

Since one and only one element can have an order of one, and the other three elements can either have an order of two or four (ignoring order).

Given this, $\mathbb{Z}_4\cong G_3$, and $\mathbb{K}_4\cong G_1$, leaving both $G_2$ and $G_4$ without a group to isomorphise with.

---

I've also seen online that a cyclic group has exactly one generating element, whereas my textbook says that a cyclic group has at least one generating element. I feel like a clarification there might clear this up. Or is it the case that $G_2$ and $G_4$ aren't possible? If so, how would I prove that (for larger orders)?

Comment: Title: There is only one classification of groups of order $4$. It says that either $G\cong C_4$ or $G\cong C_2\times C_2$.

Comment: Which textbook are you referring to?

Comment: If $g$ generates a cyclic group $G$, then its inverse $g^{-1}$ generates $G$. If the order of $G$ is greater than $2$, then $g\ne g^{-1}$..

Comment: I've edited the title, but now I see Dietrich Burde's suggestion so feel free to change it if you like that better.

Comment: @Shaun it's the Edexcel A-Levels Further Pure 2, chapter 2

Comment: @Somos I see, so the number of generating factors for an group (with an order greater than 2) cannot be odd

Comment: Exactly! That is one consequence. There can be exactly two generators if the order is $3,6,$ or infinite, and up to every non identity element is a generator if the order is a prime.

Comment: Also, if $G$ has order $n$ and is generated by $x$, then the set of generators of $G$ is precisely the set of $x^k$ where $1\leq k\leq n-1$ and $k$ is relatively prime to $n$. This set has size $\varphi(n)$, which is Euler's totient function. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$G_2$ is impossible. If $|G|=4$ and $x$ has order $4$, then $x^{-1}$ has order $4$ and is distinct from $x$. So we cannot have $(4,1)$.

$G_4$ is impossible. If $|G|=4$ and $x$ has order $4$, then $x^2$ has order $2$. And if there is no element of order $4$ then every non-identity element in $G$ has order $2$ by Lagrange's Theorem. So we cannot have $(2,0)$.

Finally, it is certainly not the case that a cyclic group has a unique generating element. Indeed, in a cyclic group of prime order, *every* non-identity element is a generator. (Perhaps you can provide a source where you saw this?)

Comment: Thanks. I think I may have read "can be generated my a single element"  as "only a single element can generate it". As for the number of generators of a cylic group, I understand now that there must be an even number of them (for groups of orders greater than 2). But doesn't that mean that for groups with an order n (which is larger than 4) there can be several cyclic groups that aren't isomorphic with each other. E.g. one has (n,2) (two generators) and the another has (n,4) (four generators). Since my book seems to imply that there can only be one cyclic group of each order (up to 8 at least)

Comment: *A priori* what you say makes sense. But it is a theorem that for any finite $n$ there is a unique cyclic group of order $n$. One will always have $\varphi(n)$ generators in a/the cyclic group of order $n$ (i.e., it is always $(n,\varphi(n))$ in your schematic). Here $\varphi$ is Euler's totient function.

Comment: See Theorem 9.8 of these notes: https://www.math.purdue.edu/~arapura/preprints/algebra9.pdf